# Angularjs NG-BOOK code cannot work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code is in this link: http://jsbin.com/gekilazilo/edit?html,js,output

I copied the code into my sublime, then ran it in a Chrome browser. The console information was as below...
"*angular.js:7861 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/ng/areq?p0=MyController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined*"

I don't know why the codes in this book always report error when I try them on my own laptop.

This is the exactly code I run.
for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    

  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="expr"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter an expression" />
    <h2>{{ parsedExpr }}</h2>
  </div>
  </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Controller2.js">
</html>
```

for Controller2.js:

```
function MyController($scope, $parse) {
   $scope.person = {
       name: "Ari Lerner"
   };
   $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
       if (newVal !== oldVal) {
         // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
         var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
         // Get the value of the parsed expression, set it on the scope for output
         scope.parsedExpr = parseFun(scope);
       }
});
};
```

Comment: There are two files here; one HTML, one JavaScript.  Did you actually **load** the JavaScript file in your HTML when you copied it?  Anyway, it seems like this question is unanswerable, because it's not related to bad code, it's related to some unknown difference in your environment that others won't be able to reproduce without making guesses, like the one I made.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited the question and uploaded the code. I'm not sure whether is the environment problem. I didn't changed my computer's environment settings before...

Comment: even if this code were to work, I wouldn't recommend writing angular this way.  Angular 1.2.x is from 2012, and significant changes have taken place with newer releases, including the removal of "global" controllers like this one and removal of support for a blank `ng-app`, for good reason.  Don't start learning a framework now from an old version using out of date syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some some closing `});` of your watch-expression

```
function MyController($scope, $parse) {
       $scope.person = {
       name: "Ari Lerner"
   };
   $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
       if (newVal !== oldVal) {
         var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
         scope.parsedExpr = parseFun(scope);
       }
  });
};
```